# SQL Server xp_delete_file parameters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

Who can explain list of `xp_Delete_file` parameters in sql server. I don't find msdn document for this stored procedure.

I got script of xp_Delete_file from maintenance plan but didn't understand first parameter.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean. OK. not exists any document in msdn. but no one know parameters and usage of these. and not exists any document in non Microsoft reference.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`xp_delete_file` take five parameters:

1. **File Type** = 0 for backup files or 1 for report files.
2. **Folder Path** =  The folder to delete files.  The path must end with a backslash "".
3. **File Extension** = This could be 'BAK' or 'TRN' or whatever you normally use.
4. **Date** = The cutoff date for what files need to be deleted.
5. **Subfolder** = 0 to ignore subfolders, 1 to delete files in
   subfolders.

*Source* [`How to Use xp_delete_file to Purge Old Backup Files`](http://www.patrickkeisler.com/2012/11/how-to-use-xpdeletefile-to-purge-old.html)  by  *Patrick Keisler*

Comment: In SQL Server 2014 at least, the second parameter (Folder Path) can be a specific filename, which results in only that one file being removed, e.g.:

EXEC master.dbo.xp_delete_file 0, 'C:\Backups\SomeDatabaseBackup.bak'

Comment: As of SQL Server 2012, the xp_delete_file generated by Maintenance Plan does **not** have a trailing backslash in Folder Path.

Answer (score 5):

Following on from the comment above, I have been testing this on SQL Server 2012 SP4 and I can confirm the syntax **EXEC master.dbo.xp_delete_file 0, 'C:\Some Path\Backup file.bak'** works and deletes the specific named file.

Answer (score 3):

I found this to be more obvious, since I like showing parameters:

```
DECLARE @DeleteDate DATETIME = DATEADD(wk,-2,GETDATE());
DECLARE @ReturnVal int

EXEC @ReturnVal = master.dbo.xp_delete_file 
    @FileType = 0,
    @FolderPath = N'U:\SQLBackups',
    @FileExtension = N'bak',
    @Date = @DeleteDate,
    @Subfolder = 1

print @ReturnVal
```

Answer (score 1):

Note the following extra information (tested on SQL Server 2019 in a Microsoft Windows environment... I can't speak for other OSs):

- the `@Date` parameter can include a time component;
- it is accurate to at least 1 second (I haven't tested milliseconds), suggesting the parameter is of type `datetime` (at least);
- the SP uses the Date *Modified* OS property (not the Date Created).