# How to delete a specifc SQL *.bak file from disk

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-backups, smo

I have a C# project, a feature of which is to copy existing SQL databases (version 2012).

To do this, I am using SMO classes `Backup` and `Restore` to back up the databases and then restore them under a new name. The database copies are restored as ‘Copy-Only’ so as not to affect the overall back and restore procedures for the database.

All of this works fine.

The issue is that I cannot seem to get rid of the *.bak file that is created when the backup is performed. I should mention the *.bak file is being created on the server box.

I have tried using a modified version of the system stored procedure `msdb.dbo.sp_delete_backuphistory`, which tries to remove all references to the backup I created from the system tables. This runs without error. However, this didn’t then trigger a clean-up of the file which I thought might happen?

I have also tried looking at `xp_delete_deletefile` but that doesn’t seem appropriate as it takes a ‘delete date’ parameter. The reason is that I only want to delete the one particular backup file that I created.

Is getting rid of a backup file a 2 stage process? (1) Delete from system tables and then (2) delete from disk? Or is there a one step process that I am not aware of?

What I am doing wrong, so that the *.bak file will be permanently deleted?

I am not at all experienced with SQL Server.

Here is a copy of the amended stored procedure:

```sql
  DECLARE @backup_set_id TABLE      (backup_set_id INT)
  DECLARE @media_set_id TABLE       (media_set_id INT)
  DECLARE @restore_history_id TABLE (restore_history_id INT)

  INSERT INTO @backup_set_id (backup_set_id)
  SELECT DISTINCT backup_set_id
  FROM msdb.dbo.backupset
  WHERE expiration_date IS NOT NULL AND expiration_date < @oldest_date AND database_name = @DBName AND is_copy_only = 1

  INSERT INTO @media_set_id (media_set_id)
  SELECT DISTINCT media_set_id
  FROM msdb.dbo.backupset
  WHERE expiration_date IS NOT NULL AND expiration_date < @oldest_date AND database_name = @DBName AND is_copy_only = 1

  INSERT INTO @restore_history_id (restore_history_id)
  SELECT DISTINCT restore_history_id
  FROM msdb.dbo.restorehistory
  WHERE backup_set_id IN (SELECT backup_set_id
                          FROM @backup_set_id)

  BEGIN TRANSACTION

  DELETE FROM msdb.dbo.backupfile
  WHERE backup_set_id IN (SELECT backup_set_id
                          FROM @backup_set_id)
  IF (@@error > 0)
    GOTO Quit

  DELETE FROM msdb.dbo.backupfilegroup
  WHERE backup_set_id IN (SELECT backup_set_id
                          FROM @backup_set_id)
  IF (@@error > 0)
    GOTO Quit

  DELETE FROM msdb.dbo.restorefile
  WHERE restore_history_id IN (SELECT restore_history_id
                               FROM @restore_history_id)
  IF (@@error > 0)
    GOTO Quit

  DELETE FROM msdb.dbo.restorefilegroup
  WHERE restore_history_id IN (SELECT restore_history_id
                               FROM @restore_history_id)
  IF (@@error > 0)
    GOTO Quit

  DELETE FROM msdb.dbo.restorehistory
  WHERE restore_history_id IN (SELECT restore_history_id
                               FROM @restore_history_id)
  IF (@@error > 0)
    GOTO Quit

  DELETE FROM msdb.dbo.backupset
  WHERE backup_set_id IN (SELECT backup_set_id
                          FROM @backup_set_id)
  IF (@@error > 0)
    GOTO Quit

  DELETE msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily
  FROM msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily bmf
  WHERE bmf.media_set_id IN (SELECT media_set_id
                             FROM @media_set_id)
    AND ((SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM msdb.dbo.backupset
          WHERE media_set_id = bmf.media_set_id) = 0)
  IF (@@error > 0)
    GOTO Quit

  DELETE msdb.dbo.backupmediaset
  FROM msdb.dbo.backupmediaset bms
  WHERE bms.media_set_id IN (SELECT media_set_id
                             FROM @media_set_id)
    AND ((SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM msdb.dbo.backupset
          WHERE media_set_id = bms.media_set_id) = 0)
  IF (@@error > 0)
    GOTO Quit

  COMMIT TRANSACTION
  RETURN

Quit:
  ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

Comment: There's a comment on [this answer to a question about xp_delete_file parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24600685/43846) - _In SQL Server 2014 at least, the second parameter (Folder Path) can be a specific filename, which results in only that one file being removed, e.g.: EXEC master.dbo.xp_delete_file 0, 'C:\Backups\SomeDatabaseBackup.bak'_

Comment: @stuartd thanks so much for your reply. Works perfectly!

Comment: @stuartd , are you able to confirm whether or not it is necessary run the amended stored proc to clean up the system tables? So, is it acceptable not to run the stored proc at all? Thanks again.

Comment: The documentation for `sp_delete_backuphistory` says _"Additional rows are added to the backup and restore history tables after each backup or restore operation is performed; **therefore, we recommend that you periodically execute sp_delete_backuphistory.**"_ so that would suggest you don't have to run it every time.